# Sort arrow appears, but does not actually sort

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a bit of code that tries to sort the values from largest to smallest in a column of a table. The graphical sort arrow appears, and the option 'largest to smallest' is indeed selected, but it's not actually sorting anything in the column. Am I referencing something incorrectly in this block of code?

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Skills]]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: See the code snippet in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add2). You need a few more lines - basically look at everything within the `With...End With`.

Comment: Where's the line with `.Apply`?

Comment: Also, line-continuation *after* the qualifying `.` dot operator for the `.SortFields` member call is rather terrible code formatting, as is the line-continuation in the middle of the `SortOn:=xlSortOnValues` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did add a With block and used .apply, works great